# Implement Hooks Using Array

Tags: hooks, actions

I'm trying to implement some hooks into a theme, but rather than write out every hook with repetitive code I was wondering if I could use and array to declare the hooks instead.

E.g. ordinarily i'd use something like:

```
function hook_name_1() {
    do_action( 'hook_name_1' );
}

function hook_name_2() {
    do_action( 'hook_name_2' );
}
```

Is there a way to place the hook names into an array and then call them with one foreach loop or something similar? Something like the following:

```
$hook_array = array(
home_name_1,
hook_name_2
);

foreach ($hook_array as $hook) {
    function $hook() {
        do_action($hook);
}
}
```

Comment: I don't know (my gut says it will work), but I'd encourage you just to try it! (And make sure that your array contains strings!)

Comment: Looks like it would work to me too. Since you've written it, how about testing it for us?

Comment: Unfortunately it results in Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_STRING or '('

Comment: Nearly there - it would seem that the $tag in the do_action needed to be global variable, but this still leaves the function names which can't be found created dynamically...

$hook_array = array( 'hook_name_1' );
foreach ($hook_array as $hook) {
function hook_name_1() {
        do_action( $GLOBALS['hook'] );
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with good old `do_action`? ;) You could write a simple wrapper:

```
    function wpse81578_hook( $hook ) {
        do_action( $hook );
    }
```

If you're looking for something dynamic, take a look at the `do_atomic` function of the [Hybrid](https://themes.svn.wordpress.org/coolstory/0.1/library/functions/core.php) theme framework: it "adds contextual action hooks to the theme.  This allows users to easily add context-based content without having to know how to use WordPress conditional tags.  The theme handles the logic."

Comment: Hi Diggy, this results in "Cannot redeclare wpse81578_hook()"

Comment: It should work just fine, in your templates, e.g. single.php:

`wpse81578_hook( 'hook_1' );echo '<hr>'; wpse81578_hook( 'hook_2' );`

and in your functions.php:

`function hook_1_test(){echo 'hook_1_test';}
add_action( 'hook_1', 'hook_1_test' );
function hook_2_test(){echo 'hook_2_test';}
add_action( 'hook_2', 'hook_2_test' );`

Comment: Just to be clear, do not wrap the code in my answer in a foreach loop. Just put those three lines in your functions.php